# GetX adding Firebase data to record

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

Im using Equatable package and getX state management package.
I built a controller which extends GetxController
I want to add my firebase datas to my Record.
How can i do it ?

This is my records which is built with equatable package

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Record extends Equatable {
 final String name;
 final String topicName;
 final String questions;
 final String answers;

 const Record({
   required this.name,
   required this.answers,
   required this.topicName,
   required this.questions,
 });

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [name, topicName, questions, answers];

 factory Record.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return Record(
       answers: 'answers',
       name: 'name',
       questions: 'questions',
       topicName: 'topicName');
 }
}
```

And this is my Controller clas which is created with GetX
I want to fill my record with firebase data

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'models/records.dart';


class Controller extends GetxController {
 var records = <Record>[].obs;

 


}
```

Comment: Check out this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#writing-data 
It will surely answer your question on how to add to firestore

Comment: i'll check thanks